# i can't get the header value from angularjs $http headers

Tags: angularjs

i set the headers in server,
resp.setHeader("Authorization", "xxxxxxx");
and the headers of http response is all right.
from the chorm,i got the info as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzHfH.png)
but from the angular $http headers function,i can't get the value i set.
i try to get value use:
console.log(response.headers());
console.log(response.headers("Authorization"));

the console print:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5gR8.png)

how to get the value?
tks

Answer (score 1):

you can get header in angular like this

```
                   $http.get(_uri, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                              .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                                  if (status === 200) {
                                      headers = headers();
                                      var content = headers['content-disposition'].split('=');

                                  } else {

                                  }
                              })
```

Comment: $http.get(BASE_URL + "/authKaptcha/captcha.jpg?a=", { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                    if (status === 200) {
                        headers = headers();
                        //var content = headers['content-disposition'].split('=');
                        console.log(headers['content-disposition']);
                    }
                })

i just want to get a image from server,but console print undefined